# Bad vertical distance in table using makecell package \multirowhead

Tags: tables, multirow, tabu, makecell

This is my working code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{makecell}
\oddsidemargin   16mm
\evensidemargin  -3mm
\topmargin      -3mm
\headheight      5mm
\headsep         7mm
\textheight      228mm
\textwidth       146mm
\footskip        8mm   
\begin{document}
\makegapedcells
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\theadset{\def\arraystretch{.85}}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[1pt]}   
\begin{table}[h]
\label{tab:table30B}
\begin{center}
%7 columns
\small
\begin{tabu}{|[2pt] c|[2pt] c| c| c| c| c| c|[2pt]}
\tabucline[2pt]{-}  
\multirowthead{3}[9ex][l]{\parbox{3cm}{xxx xxxx xxxxx experxxxx cc xxx xxxx xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxexxxmexx xxxxx?}} & \multicolumn{6}{c|[2pt]}{\thead{XX XXXX XX XXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX\\ / XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXr XXXX?}}\\
\cline{2-7}
&NeXX&  \thead{XXXXX\\ ($< \,10\,\%$)}&\thead{Reaso-\\nably}&   \thead{XXarly\\ ($> XX\,\%$\\ and $< XX\,\%$)}& \thead{XXXX\\ XXX\\ ($> XXX \,\%$)}&    \thead{XXXXX}\\
\cline{2-7}

& \thead{Count}&    \thead{Count}&  \thead{Count}&  \thead{Count}&  \thead{Count}&  \thead{Count}   \\

\tabucline[2pt]{-}
X\,--\,XX (XXXXX)& 7&   2&  11& 1&  0&  31\\
XXX\,--\,15 (XXXXX)&    31& 1&  3&  2&  1&  10\\
15\,--\,20 (XXXXX)& 12& 0& 4&   7&  0&  X\\
XX,--\,XX (XXXXX)&  0&  0&  1&  0&  0&  1\\
XXXX XX (XXXXX)&0&  3&  X&  0& 2&   3\\
Total&  11& 16& X& 3&   1&  48\\
\tabucline[2pt]{-}
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This what I have:

[image]

As you can see 2-7 multicolumn row has huge vertical distances. How I could remove them?
As I understand there is a problem with \multirowhead command, but I can not figure out what I could do with it. I've tried different things, this is a best I could get by so far.

Please Help me to solve this problem using makecell package. Usually this package gives very nice results in constructing tables.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to solve it, but it is mainly a trick. The first line in tabu environment

```
\multirowthead{3}[9ex][l]{\parbox{3cm}{xxx xxxx xxxxx experxxxx cc xxx xxxx xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxexxxmexx xxxxx?}} & \multicolumn{6}{c|[2pt]}{\thead{XX XXXX XX XXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX\\ / XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXr XXXX?}}\\
```

should be replaced by this code:

```
\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{\footnotesize \vspace{2mm}Xxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxx xx total xx the xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx field?}} & \multicolumn{6}{c|[2pt]}{\thead{Xxx xxxx xx xxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx / xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxx}}\\
```

Then in conclusion:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{makecell}
\oddsidemargin   16mm
\evensidemargin  -3mm
\topmargin      -3mm
\headheight      5mm
\headsep         7mm
\textheight      228mm
\textwidth       146mm
\footskip        8mm   
\begin{document}
\makegapedcells
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\theadset{\def\arraystretch{.85}}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[1pt]}   
\begin{table}[h]
\label{tab:table30B}
\begin{center}
%7 columns
\small
\begin{tabu}{|[2pt] c|[2pt] c| c| c| c| c| c|[2pt]}
\tabucline[2pt]{-}  
\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{\footnotesize \vspace{2mm}Xxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxx xx total xx the xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx field?}} & \multicolumn{6}{c|[2pt]}{\thead{Xxx xxxx xx xxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx / xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxx}}\\
\cline{2-7}
&NeXX&  \thead{XXXXX\\ ($< \,10\,\%$)}&\thead{Reaso-\\nably}&   \thead{XXarly\\ ($> XX\,\%$\\ and $< XX\,\%$)}& \thead{XXXX\\ XXX\\ ($> XXX \,\%$)}&    \thead{XXXXX}\\
\cline{2-7}

& \thead{Count}&    \thead{Count}&  \thead{Count}&  \thead{Count}&  \thead{Count}&  \thead{Count}   \\

\tabucline[2pt]{-}
X\,--\,XX (XXXXX)& 7&   2&  xx& 1&  x&  31\\
XXX\,--\,15 (XXXXX)&    xx& 1&  3&  2&  1&  10\\
15\,--\,20 (XXXXX)& 12& x& 4&   7&  x&  X\\
XX,--\,XX (XXXXX)&  0&  0&  1&  x&  0&  x\\
XXXX XX (XXXXX)&0&  3&  X&  0& 2&   3\\
Total&  11& 16& X& 3&   x&  48\\
\tabucline[2pt]{-}
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]